# Access assets folder in iText pdf library in android

Tags: android

I want to write some image from assets folder to pdf file using iText library.
If I access using sdcard then it work fine.
But if I access using assets folder then it display file not found exception.
My code is

```
package com.app.ipro;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Date;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;

import com.itextpdf.text.Anchor;
import com.itextpdf.text.BadElementException;
import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.Chapter;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.List;
import com.itextpdf.text.ListItem;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.Section;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class MakeInvoice {
    private static String FILE = "";

    public static void main() {
        try {
            String externalStoragePath = Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            System.out.println("externalStoragePath:" + externalStoragePath);
            boolean f = new File(externalStoragePath + "\\MyPDF").mkdirs();
            System.out.println("f:" + f);
            FILE = externalStoragePath + "\\MyPDF\\" + "FirstPdfabc6.pdf";
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));
            document.open();
            addMetaData(document);
            addTitlePage(document);
            document.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private static void addMetaData(Document document) {
        document.addTitle("My first PDF");
        document.addSubject("Using iText");
        document.addKeywords("Java, PDF, iText");
        document.addAuthor("Lars Vogel");
        document.addCreator("Lars Vogel");
    }

    private static void addTitlePage(Document document)
            throws DocumentException {
        Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();
        addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
        preface.add(new Paragraph("Title of the document"));

        addEmptyLine(preface, 1);

        document.add(preface);
        String strLogo = "file:///android_asset/tmpl1/Vector_background1.jpg";


        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.setTableEvent(new tableEvent(strLogo));
        table.addCell("Name");
        table.addCell("Place");
        table.addCell("RoseIndia");
        table.addCell("Delhi");
        document.add(table);

        document.newPage();
    }

    private static void addEmptyLine(Paragraph paragraph, int number) {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            paragraph.add(new Paragraph(" "));
        }
    }
}
```

and in table event i have write

```
package com.app.ipro;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import com.itextpdf.text.BadElementException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTableEvent;


public class tableEvent implements PdfPTableEvent{
    String img;
    public tableEvent(String imgPath){
        img = imgPath;
    }

    @Override
    public void tableLayout(PdfPTable arg0, float[][] arg1, float[] arg2,
            int arg3, int arg4, PdfContentByte[] arg5) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = arg5[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS];
        Image bgImage;
        try {
            bgImage = Image.getInstance(img);
            bgImage.setAbsolutePosition(10, 10);
            bgImage.setWidthPercentage(50);
            pdfContentByte.addImage(bgImage);
        } catch (BadElementException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

so run time it shows exception,

```
08-11 15:24:45.817: WARN/System.err(18022): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android_asset/tmpl1/Vector_background1.jpg (No such file or directory)
08-11 15:24:45.837: WARN/System.err(18022):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.openImpl(Native Method)
08-11 15:24:45.837: WARN/System.err(18022):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(OSFileSystem.java:152)
08-11 15:24:45.847: WARN/System.err(18022):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:82)
08-11 15:24:45.857: WARN/System.err(18022):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:85)
08-11 15:24:45.857: WARN/System.err(18022):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:184)
08-11 15:24:45.867: WARN/System.err(18022):     at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:653)
08-11 15:24:45.867: WARN/System.err(18022):     at com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(Image.java:245)
08-11 15:24:45.877: WARN/System.err(18022):     at com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(Image.java:341)
08-11 15:24:45.877: WARN/System.err(18022):     at com.app.ipro.tableEvent.tableLayout(tableEvent.java:28)
08-11 15:24:45.897: WARN/System.err(18022):     at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:731)
08-11 15:24:45.897: WARN/System.err(18022):     at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(PdfPTable.java:824)
08-11 15:24:45.907: WARN/System.err(18022):     at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.goComposite(ColumnText.java:1524)
08-11 15:24:45.907: WARN/System.err(18022):     at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:807)
08-11 15:24:45.907: WARN/System.err(18022):     at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:795)
08-11 15:24:45.907: WARN/System.err(18022):     at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.addPTable(PdfDocument.java:2361)
08-11 15:24:45.907: WARN/System.err(18022):     at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.add(PdfDocument.java:673)
08-11 15:24:45.917: WARN/System.err(18022):     at com.itextpdf.text.Document.add(Document.java:282)
08-11 15:24:45.927: WARN/System.err(18022):     at com.app.ipro.MakeInvoice.addTitlePage(MakeInvoice.java:87)
08-11 15:24:45.927: WARN/System.err(18022):     at com.app.ipro.MakeInvoice.main(MakeInvoice.java:45)
08-11 15:24:45.937: WARN/System.err(18022):     at com.app.ipro.Other$1.onClick(Other.java:47)
08-11 15:24:45.937: WARN/System.err(18022):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
08-11 15:24:45.937: WARN/System.err(18022):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
08-11 15:24:45.947: WARN/System.err(18022):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-11 15:24:45.947: WARN/System.err(18022):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-11 15:24:45.967: WARN/System.err(18022):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-11 15:24:45.967: WARN/System.err(18022):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-11 15:24:45.977: WARN/System.err(18022):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 15:24:45.977: WARN/System.err(18022):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-11 15:24:45.987: WARN/System.err(18022):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-11 15:24:45.987: WARN/System.err(18022):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-11 15:24:45.987: WARN/System.err(18022):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If I refer same image from sdcard then it work perfect, but I want to do using assets folder.
Please help me to come out

Answer (score 0):

we can open image from assets via input stream only. so first open image as input stream and then save it to a temporary location and then give saved image path to tableEvent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So for that I have to again refer sdcard. Is there other way to save in application folder only rather then sdcard?

Comment: ya sure, you can also save it in your application cache directory. After you created pdf and other things finally delete that image from cache directory. So no need to save it in sd card?